# Determining a model for a specific vector-borne disease

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, model, biostatistics

I feel like I should do a little introduction before asking the question just to make sure we're on the same page. I'm fairly new to statistics, so  any help is appreciated and I apologize in advance if the terminology is not 100% or if I don't understand correctly an answer. I can work my way around R and GeoDa.

I'm trying to understand which variables affect the number of cases of Chagas Disease in the brazilian state of Pará. The state itself is subdivided into 144 municipalities and that's the scale of my data. I'm taking into account climatic data, socioeconomical data and land use at one entry a year for each municipality for a 10-year period (2004 - 2014) .

**Climatic data:**

- Average maximum temperature (°C);
- Average minimum temperature (°C);
- Average relative humidity (%);
- Average precipitation (mm);

**Land use data:**

- Percentage of vegetation/ municipality (%);
- Percentage of human niche (I estimated the area humans occupy on each municipality by adding the area of cities + farmlands) (%);

**Socioeconomical data:**

- Production of Açaí palm fruits (the vector lives within these palm trees)(tons);
- Nº of cases per municipality **(Dependant variable!!)**;

My objective is to determine whether there is spatial dependence on the cases of Chagas Disease. For that, I thought of using a model that doesn't take the spatial dependence into account, testing for spatial dependence and, if the significance is positive, run a model that takes it into account (SLM or SEM, depending on the results).

I don't have a very good idea on how to choose the correct model for my problem, but my supervisor said that a *glm assuming a poisson distribution* should work fine. The thing is, the glm function on R doesn't take into account that the data is organized in a time series. Is there any way to do so? What is the function I'm looking for?

Also, I have some additional questions:

1) From all 144 municipalities, roughly 30 of them (less than 25%) presented cases of the given disease. Trying to run a model for the entire state isn't going to affect the accuracy of my model? Should I stick to a **n** where 50% of the municipalities presented cases and the other 50% didn't?

2) How about the neighborhood matrix for thespatial dependence analysis? How to determine which one is the more accurate?